# Confusion of quantifier statement answer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Let I(x) be “x has an internet connection” and let
>   C(x, y) be “x and y have chatted over the internet.” Assume
>   the universe of discourse consists of all students in your class.
>   Express the following using quantifiers.
>
> There are two students in the class who between them
>   have chatted with everyone else in the class.
>
> The answer of all the websites:∃x∃y(x≠y∧∀z(C(x,z)∨C(y,z))).
>
> doesn't should it be ∃x∃y(x≠y∧(∀z(C(x,z)∨∀z(C(y,z))))?

Because their answers state that there exists two different person x y ,for every people,either x will chat with him or y will.

is it my misunderstanding of the question or the answer of internet is wrong.

Comment: You are asserting that either $x$ has chatted with everyone, or that $y$ has chatted with everyone.

Comment: doesn't the question mean that x  has chatted with everyone or that y has chatted with everyone or both?

Comment: No, this English idiom means that each person has chatted to one of $x$ and $y$. So maybe half the class have chatted to $x$ and the remaining half to $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the expression "between them", I think. This means, e.g. that in the class everyone has chatted with $x$ or with $y$ (but not necessarily with both of them) (or in graph terms these two points form a "vertex cover" of the "chat graph"). Your disjunction means that all $z$ have chatted with $x$, **or** or all $z$ have chatted with $y$, which is very different. That's why

$$\forall z:(C(z,x) \lor C(z,y))$$ is correct.